# How to clear symfony cache without deleting the profiler data

Tags: symfony

I am trying to use inotify to automatically clear symfony cache every time a file gets modified. The issue is that `cache:clear` also removes profiler data, and I would like to keep it.

Is there a way to run cache:clear without deleting the profiler data?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what's the reason to clear the whole cache every time a file gets modified?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use any other type of cache than the filesystem? If not, you could remove the files manually instead of calling `cache:clear`: locate `var/cache/dev` in your application and remove everything in there except the `profiler` folder

---

Also, you could change the folder where the profiler's data is stored. In your package configuration (which should be in `config/packages/web_profiler.yaml`), use `framework.profiler.dsn`for this, for example like this:

```yaml
when@dev:
    web_profiler:
        toolbar: true
        intercept_redirects: false

    framework:
        profiler:
            only_exceptions: false
            dsn: 'file:%kernel.project_dir%/var/profiler'
```

This would move the profiler's storage folder to `var/profiler`, and calling `cache:clear` won't remove it